# How to solve complex trigonometry equations

Tags: complex-analysis

How would you approach to solve questions like:

$\sin(z)=\sin(2)$, $z$ is an arbitrary complex number.

Comment: Does it work in the complex field as well?

Comment: $\sin x=\sin y$ iff $x=y+2n\pi $ or $x=(\pi-y)+2n\pi$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the trigonometry equations for real numbers still holds in the complex region. We still have
$$ \sin(z) = \sin(x) \iff z = x + 2\pi n \mathrm{\ or\ } z = \pi - x + 2\pi n$$
for some integer $n$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this question, you need to recall how the sine is defined.
We have $\sin(z)=\frac {e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$.
Since the exponential function is periodic with period $2\pi i$, this implies that the sine is periodic with period $2 \pi$, just as for real arguments.